# What's wrong with this question about debugging?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797571/how-do-i-debug-error-at-object-f-loadjs-arcgis-com-3-19-init-js980

I don't actually see the problem here. Why does this have 4 down votes? I googled the error before I asked and I got nothing. It's well formatted. Is it because my name is Steve?

Comment: You have a comment telling you exactly what the problem is.  Why are you asking us when you've already been told what the problem is?

Comment: "Please share the code snippet in which the error occurs or create a fiddle for the same" Are you talking about this? Cause the code snippet wasn't something I had, nor was it actually important to the question I was asking.

Comment: You don't describe where/how you encountered this error at all. What code were you running that threw this error? Was it a script of yours? Something on the command line?  You say that the code snippet isn't important to the question, but how would you know that if you don't know what the issue is?

Comment: @DavyM Don't I only need to include that if I'm asking for help debugging the error?

Comment: @HansPassant How would using a telephone help in that situation?

Comment: I'm well aware that you've said that you can't provide enough information in your question to make it answerable.  That doesn't mean it's not important to your question that you provide enough information to make it answerable.  The comments you've gotten and the votes on it are reflecting that.

Comment: @Servy so you're saying it got down voted because I didn't have enough information to make the question I wasn't asking answerable? What should I have done in that situation? Cause I did get rewarded at work for how I handled the situation as a whole. I just don't understand why SO is mad at me.

Comment: @Steve "so you're saying it got down voted because I didn't have enough information to make the question I wasn't asking answerable?" - I dunno. Maybe try, "providing enough information to make the question answerable"?

Comment: @Steve You should provide enough information in your question for it to be answerable.  Or not posted the question.

Comment: @Mysticial I didn't have that. If I did, I wouldn't have bothered asking...

Comment: @Servy I asked for a method to debug the problem and I got a method. Should I have asked for the method on a different SE site?

Comment: @Steve If you're just looking to ask, "how do I debug any javascript problem" then that question is way too broad, and most certainly isn't answerable.

Comment: What we don't know is where this error is coming from in the slightest. This could be anything from an error message you're seeing when powering on your computer to an error message that you're getting when downloading an app on your phone to an error thrown when running a specific command in a script of yours. Additionally, someone asked you for more information, and you decided that it was not relevant. The only real debugging help a person can actually give is "Try rebooting" because we assume this happened on something electronic. You need to include more information.

Comment: @DavyM Now it just sounds like you're complaining cause the problem was too hard. GibboK had literally no problem working with that information. Are you upset because you feel like the question was unfair since you couldn't answer it? Is that why everyone wanted to be able to point to something in my code and answer a question that I wasn't asking!?

Comment: @DavyM Can you run into errors when you don't run code!? I realize you deleted your comment or something, but I honestly didn't know this was possible. Not trying to throw shade.

Comment: Steve?  Steve who?  From what company?  Hmmkay, I must have missed the memo.  Are you trying to tell me there is a bug in my code??  That seems rather unlikely, it was thoroughly tested by Jimmy.  How are you using my code, can you send me a repro?  What do you mean "no"?

Comment: @HansPassant I thought I did include the repro though. What's a repro? I don't understand enough to understand your comment.

Comment: Well, that *is* the problem.  You have to break out of your cubicle and make your life more complicated.  It is the only way to do it, SO does not provide an alternative.  Unpleasant,  but you'll be happy with the end-result.  First real win and all that, second time is going to be much easier.

Comment: @Hans Passant I was out of my cubicle. This wasn't even my code. Someone asked me for help and I gave it to them... Are you saying I should have called every one in my office - of which I'm the most advanced programmer - so that they could all stare at a screen with me?

Comment: @HansPassant You're saying that I should find another job because I asked a bad SO question? I asked a bad SO question cause I'm not very advanced in programming. I'm honestly still only at the beginner level. How could I even get another job in this field? I'm just trying to find a way to ask this question better aside from "don't ask it dumbass".

Comment: You'll have to make up your mind whether you are "not very advanced" or the "most advanced programmer in the office".  The first statement is normal, the second one is easy to fix.

Comment: @HansPassant I actually don't because they're both true. I'm not very advanced and still the most advanced programmer - by leagues mind you- in the office... Have you only worked at google or something? The only people in the office who program are people I've taught. We generally don't run into problems that often. That's something we haven't seen before and we haven't seen since.

Comment: You don't seem every inspired with what you do every day, forty hours a week, the prime hours of your life.  You only have one.  Clearly I don't understand that attitude, I'm sure I never will.  Typical hazard of an SO contributor.

Comment: @HansPassant Dude I'm part time.... Why would you assume I'm full time?

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean I'm not committed to this meta question? Do you think I'd be here trying to extract value from you if I wasn't? I've been trying to get every last bit of value from this meta question this entire time when all you've been doing is taking digs at me. Why do you think I'm not committed? Why would someone who wasn't committed even waste their time talking to you?

Comment: This is starting to sound like an Eliza transcript. I'm hitting ^-C

Comment: @JoshCaswell: do you often feel this way?

Comment: The TL;DR here is "You asked a question that wasn't appropriate for SO".... just learn from this and make your next question better. At the end of the day, SO isn't for ALL questions related to programming, and that's okay

Comment: TL;DR: [Make a MCVE ("repro")](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364280/whats-wrong-with-this-question-about-debugging#comment563211_364280), [don't ask too generically, as it's too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364280/whats-wrong-with-this-question-about-debugging#comment563200_364280). Otherwise your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Patrice I believe the asker is still question banned, as per his previous Meta question.

Comment: @fbueckert yepp. I've completely given up on this account too so I'm just going to ask how I messed up every question I have before moving on to something else. Probably a different website honestly. It's starting to become clear that SO isn't useful to me.

Comment: @user202729 That's just a link to my question. What's a repro?

Comment: @user202729 so you don't know what a repro is either? Most of my questions didn't get feedback till I started asking about them.

Comment: Hm? I thought I [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the MCVE page in the previous comment? Didn't I?

Comment: The question(Q) this Q refers to can't be seen anymore, which lowers the usefulness of this Q.

It seems to me that Steve HAS made clear why he hasn't posted code, and Servy and others, just aren't (weren't) hearing it:  Steve said straight out, "the code snippet wasn't something I had".  *He doesn't have the source code.*  So his Q is entirely out of scope, as Steve just has the binary, no?  (I suppose Steve could post the binary and folks could help him debug it that way (Security-focused lessons do teach object code debugging skills...) but that's not what SO is for, right?)

Comment: @MatthewElvey at this point I don't even have that. Deleting the question was the only way I could stop people from downvoting it. It ended up being -16. Pretty much nothing I could do about this. I didn't even write the code I was trying to debug, nor did anyone in my office write it. I'm betting the company we got it from doesn't know who wrote it either. This is by far the worst response I've ever gotten from asking a question, irl or otherwise. I did eventually get an answer in the comments of another meta post where someone was making fun of me over this question. Only there was I (1/2)

Comment: @MatthewElvey finally able to convince them that I actually did not know how to debug this and wasn't being lazy. This was at least 6 months later.

Comment: @Steve, when you say, "at this point I don't even have that," it's ambiguous what you're referring to.  

More so because you later say, "I didn't even write the code I was trying to debug," and had earlier said, "I ... didn't even know which part of the 5k+ lines of code the error was coming from."

Comment: @MatthewElvey I don't have the code anymore. We deleted that app and made another one. We don't have a copy of the old app nor the code anymore. I would have liked to has asked a more detailed question. I should really delete this account and start over. I should have more than 127 rep to show for 3.5 years here.

Answer (score 26):

How is it possible that one has an issue with code that clearly throws an error, yet **they omit the code that throws the error**, and only provide us a stack trace?  We cannot read minds, nor can we infer based on context alone.  We ***require*** the source code that actually shows what has broken in your environment.  Without that I'm not clear what you expect from us.

Comment: But I didn't ask for you to solve my bug. I asked for direction in solving it myself. I also got exactly what I asked for from a user. I also explained that I didn't have access to the code and didn't even know which part of the 5k+ lines of code the error was coming from. There was no way for me to give you that information.

Comment: ...Did you write the code that somehow generated that error then?  Or where did it come from? (These are the things I'm talking about; context and missing details would be invaluable here.)

Comment: @Steve everyone is telling you the same thing. It's okay that you want to solve it yourself, however you need to give context. That is the answer to your question. Nobody is saying that you are wrong for wanting to debug your code, they are all just saying at east some information about how you encountered this error is necessary to be a good question.

Comment: @Makoto no I did not. I don't know who wrote it honestly.

Comment: @Steve:  So you inherited code from someone that uses this library?

Comment: @Makoto They used a bunch of files. I suppose it was a library. I don't know which one.

Comment: So here's the deal.  You're a *lot* closer to the code that's causing the error @Steve.  You need to narrow down where the error is occurring.  Isolating where the problem actually is with your code is fundamental - I don't want to say "fundamental" since this is more like "breathing" -  to your ability to debug, diagnose and fix code.  It's also a hard requirement for anyone looking for help from this community.  Without code, we're not much better than the wall.

Comment: @Makoto so It got downvoted cause the question I asked was too hard. Are you just supposed to use stack overflow for easy questions that you can't solve with google that are outside of your expertise?

Comment: @Steve: No, it got downvoted because **all you gave us was a stack trace** and **we can't help you debug your code if there _is_ no code.**

Comment: @Steve It's not a hard question because the issue is difficult, it's a hard question because it is poorly written because it provides no context. That's why it is being downvoted, because it is a poor question.

Comment: @Makoto so seeing that there wasn't a way at the time for me to give you anything but that should I have put "All I have is a stack trace" at the beginning of the question? Should I change the title to something about isolating a bug?

Comment: @DavyM Outside of the code that I stated I didn't have, what other context could I have added?

Comment: If all you really have is a stack trace, keep looking.  We're not going to be of much value.  Even the answer you received is telling you to **post some code** which reproduces the problem.  It's tough to tell if you needed help with this problem or if you didn't know how to actually debug your code, which are different (yet not mutually exclusive) problems to have.

Comment: @Makoto I literally put that I wanted a method in the question. How would I have made it more clear that I didn't know how to actually debug code? Is that a title thing?

Comment: That's...okay.  Now I see what's going on.  That's a much, much harder thing to deal with since we kind of assume that you *do* know how to debug your code...so it's not surprising at all that you received so much flak because you literally didn't know how to do what it is we were jumping up and down/screaming at you to do. ...Hmm.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for finally realizing the problem. I've been seriously disturbed about this. Also can you edit your answer to include your method if you come up with one. Should I rephrase this question too since people still don't seem to understand?

Comment: Gonna be frank:  I'm disturbed too, but for different reasons.  Honestly I'm not sure if we can help you all that well since...I don't think we've ever supported users who haven't been able to debug their code.

Comment: @Steve Whatever it is that you did to encounter this error. You had to have done something, or else the stack trace just magically appeared out of no where. The answer that you said helped **guessed** that you encountered this error running an application that you would be able to debug and gave you a link to DevTools which would work for that circumstance. But you are saying you didn't have that code, so I would fail to understand how on earth the answer managed to help you anyways. Ergo, you must have had an application, and that application failed with this stack trace. There's Context.

Comment: @Makoto It wasn't my code and I did get help. I just got downvoted to oblivion for it.

Comment: @DavyM ah, okay I'll add that in right now. Can you make that comment an answer for this question. I know I'm not the only person on this site running into this problem.

Comment: @Steve I'm actually headed out the door, but later if there's time I will.

Comment: Maybe the post should have been closed as a dupe of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: @AndrewMyers It's 100% going away now since it was put on hold.

Comment: @Steve Actually, it's not going away at all, unless you delete it yourself (or get your account deleted). There is an accepted answer, and the answer is not downvoted, so the question won't be automatically deleted.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I can't delete it. Is there anything else helpful that I can actually do with that question or with this question?