# Should the goal of Stack Overflow be defined and expressed more clearly?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based, community-moderation

**tldr;** People get misunderstood a lot on here, existing users trying to help, and new users with the overall goals of the site. New users need redirected instead of boiler plates, other sites exist for new programmers and should be recommended. Main point of contention is attitudes on both sides.

I strongly believe Stack Overflow has a problem, and that it isn't just a loud minority of elitist users, but instead the reputation the site has gained as a "go here, get help" forum.

Most new users coming to this site are rookie programmers or at least new enough that their code and posts will have duplicates, but not exact enough that all the answers fit. From what I've seen and read in the small time here, the rules, and the general meta of the forum push a narrative that Stack Overflow is an archive of questions and answers, which itself is a ridiculous goal to pursue as you've got to ask stupid questions from time to time to get a build up of good answers and faux-elitism means nobody will come here after asking a single question and getting downvoted because they misunderstood an answer or criticised someone with high rep who treats the forum like a job and therefore *has no chill* for lack of better phrasing.

I think a solution for all the misunderstandings is either to drop the pursuit of the idea of turning Stack Overflow into a resource, as that's not what forums should be designed to be, and it seems to be a community guided thing that the very community fails to make obvious to new visitors, or, make it clearer that this is not a place for new programmers to ask for help. To clarify, a new programmer does not want to hear "Oh god why are you using x, that was made bad practise ages ago, use y instead", unless you're willing to also explain why not to use x and why y is better practice, so people can actually learn. Make it clear what the community intention for the forums are and **kindly** redirect new programmers or folks with basic problems to better resources where they can get support and not rampant criticism.

***Edit:*** The main issue I think needs to be looked at is a combination of newcomer perception, and existing users' burnout: New people aren't looking at the tour or reading the help desk, these should be made much more obvious, have some sort of pop up that's not a pop up for all new users that practically fills the screen detailing the goals and intentions of the site and community, this should dissuade anyone treating it like a help site for new programmers which it's often confused for. Have existing users understand that this is not their job, they are volunteers, they do not have to answer every question and therefore they cannot rely on "I saw this x amount of times before" as an excuse for being unkind or brazen. The community would be improved drastically if people had an ounce of sympathy popped into them intravenously before they posted a comment or an answer, as mentioned in the comments, people are often frustrated when they make a post here, they are not always in the best of moods, users should be understanding of that.

**Further Edit:** After making this post, users have used it as a pivot to go to my StackOverflow posts and downvote them, this is clearly not because they are just bad questions, but as a reaction to this meta post. This is only evidence of a problem in the community, they might not have been perfect posts, but the negative attention is purely vindictive in nature and acts as downvote bombing.

Comment: "Most new users coming to this site are rookie programmers" Gonna have to ask for a citation on that. It would probably also be easier to take you seriously if you skipped the ad hominem about "elitist users" and accusing people of treating this site as a "job".

Comment: Stack Overflow is a resource. I use it every day, successfully. Whatever happens surrounding it, it is still a treasure trove of answers coated with sugar, spice and everything nice. The repository is "fine" although it will forever need a spit polish, it's everything around it that is cracking. People, mostly.

Comment: @ivarni I can't provide a citation for that, only anecdotal evidence that people on other programming and computing forums do commonly reference StackOverflow as the place they go when they don't know something. If you don't believe there is an air of elitism amongst some users, then I have to question your judgement, there is a definite group, no matter how small, of users that refuse to even help with code unless it's written how they like it. They do treat it like a job as one user complained about having to read long code as if they were forced to, but they aren't this isn't a job.

Comment: @Gimby the people are an issue when they violate the site's own code of conduct and downvote dissenting opinions. I do use StackOverflow to see if a question I have has already been answered, but due to attitudes and egos, I'll be sticking to other sites when I need to ask a question myself.

Comment: Nitpicking, not a forum. It's a question and answer site. More like a community FAQ. The idea is to have good and quality. It's hard to warp the head around it at first. We came with a sense of urgency. The negative feedback, is a feedback. Getting  throws back to [mre] and [ask] have improve my communication skill. It leave only the duplicate case. Well duplicate are not a bad thing, if it's good an clear enought it won't get downvoted.

Comment: @xdtTransform it can't be considered a Q&A if you're not allowed to ask questions. I would happily welcome feedback, but sometimes folks are just negative and not helpful at all, preferring to argue instead of give actual feedback. The people who actually answer questions aren't the ones at fault, just high-reps that lurk in the comments.

Comment: _Stack Overflow is an archive of questions and answers, which itself is a ridiculous goal to pursue_ The goal is not at all ridiculous, instead this is what that kept SO to move on forward and be great, it is however revealed that this goal is completed

Comment: @weegee and if that is the intent, make efforts to make the goal more obvious so that people don't come here looking for solutions to problems that most the regulars here consider beneath them and their little archive.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn while it might be difficult for newcomers sometimes (and appears to be something SE is trying to address), downvoting is not a violition of the CoC.

Comment: @Druckles I have not claimed that downvoting is a violation of the CoC though? I said that high-rep users violate CoC and there is a habit of downvoting a post you don't agree with. Those are separate, but it would be appreciated if users had to state a reason for downvoting to dissuade passive downvotes.

Comment: Problems that _contribute_ something to this site are always kept. Why should we discourage people looking for solutions?

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn, "it can't be considered a Q&A if you're not allowed to ask questions", everyone is allowed to ask question till the system time them out to give them time to improve thier previous question.

Comment: @weegee but the strict criteria of what makes a contribution, despite the amount of posts on it, isn't clear enough for the people most likely to make the *copypasta question* posts.

Comment: What is not clear enough? At least lead with that? I cannot see anything in your post that says which part or line is unclear.

Comment: @MartinJames and that "TLDR" attitude doesn't help when it's mirrored by 12 other people on the comments of a post. Once one person says, "this is a dupe, look here", the question should be closed. The duplicate comments are more irritating than duplicate posts.

Comment: @weegee things like telling new users to make reprex' because you can't be bothered to read code, which rely on having a decent amount of knowledge in the language you're writing in is one recent example. The "Our Model" section of the help centre should just be rewritten to be more newcomer friendly and should be required reading somehow to post questions.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn the duplicate comment is automatically generated when somebody votes or flags a question as a duplicate. The UI makes it mandatory to choose which is the duplicate question, once you do the vote/flag is recorded and the message is automatically generated and posted in your name.

Comment: Looking at your profile your last burn was a case of no [MRE]. Minimal is a important thing because people airdrop question with too many code / 2mo github project. Bacically it's nothing more than commenting everything till you have the issue and commenting anything will stop the error. The most funny thing with MRE is that you do it and solve 90% of your problems yourself

Comment: @xdtTransform and if you actually read the comments on that post, you'd understand that reprex isn't that simple when someone is learning a language. As you said, most the time when you reprex code you actually find the problem. Unfortunately to reprex the code you need to know the problem because that determines what exactly is relevant. The "too many code" argument is ridiculous, if a post is too long, don't read it, don't interact with it. Don't ask for a TLDR if it's assumed users have already read the MRE guide, like I had before posting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.", that's not entirely relevant for this post or focused on this topic, instead completely reliant on my other post, not even contextually relevant here. Good job showing one of the qualities I pointed out. Now, if the community wanted to be helpful, and what would make a "quality and archive-worthy" comment, would be to give a brief explanation of how to easily get into debugging your own code, linking a few other resources.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you read the post, I said the rules should either be changed to fit common use, or the intent of the site made more obvious to newcomers.

Comment: *"The "Our Model" section of the help centre should just be rewritten to be more newcomer friendly and should be required reading somehow to post  Problem is, newcomers *are* directed to the site rules when they arrive. Most simply do not read them. I cannot count the number of times I've had to explain these rules to "new contributors". Often, people are in such a hurry to post their problem they simply cannot concentrate on anything extraneous.

Comment: How do you make the intent any more obvious? There is a tour you are encouraged to take an a bunch of articles about how to ask, what questions are acceptable and what aren't. That should define the purpose of the site quite clearly. Is any of these resources ambiguous and where?

Comment: @CindyMeister and despite having read them, I still have had to encounter vitriolic comments on numerous posts because someone didn't meet the expectations of another user. If it's evident someone hasn't read them, redirect them.

Comment: Remembering that everyone who answers questions on this site is a volunteer, and usually a professional who gets paid for coding: Do you feel it's fair that they should need to hold the hands of people who can't be bothered to put in a minimum of effort when asking a question? How much patience can one have with people who come here with the *expectation* that others will do their work for them, or provide a tutorial that's available elsewhere?

Comment: @VLAZ I myself have never encountered any such tour, and from most of what I've read, including the aforementioned "Our Model" section of the help centre, there's a sort of internal confusion where the site is both portrayed as a help desk and an archive.

Comment: @CindyMeister if a child misbehaves, a parent helps them. If children misbehave in a daycare centre, the employees help them. My point being, the quantity of a problem should not impact your reaction to the problem, if you're fed up and impatient, **take a break**, it's not your job, like you mentioned, you're a volunteer.

Comment: (We're crossing in our writing...) When presenting one side of the problem, it's important to keep the other side's POV in mind. The company is aware of the kinds of issues you describe and is trying to address them. With how much success is perhaps debatable, but the intent is there. Also, there are always "black sheep" - for those helping here who *try* to keep a balance, it's difficult to accept blanket accusations.

Comment: When you encounter... unreasonable comments you can **flag** them for removal. "No longer needed" is one reason listed; "Unfriendly/unkind" is another; "rude/abusive" is also in the list. Using these is encouraged. Not only can you get rid of comments that add nothing to solving the problem, it also helps keep the site "clean" for others who later read a discussion.

Comment: @CindyMeister but I feel that the community has shaped itself around the current state of the site, the company itself can't really do much about it except provide tools like the flagging system you've mentioned, but then it's up to a moderator to decide what happens with the comment, and I honestly have no faith in them due to a general lack of faith in the community because of their treatment to newcomers. The post people brought up earlier, that was already answered and I desired it to be closed, there were duplicate, irrelevant comments and no way to remove them.

Comment: RE "children misbehaving": This is a rather basic misconception about the site - it does not target "children", or absolute beginners. A certain basic understanding of the coding language involved is expected. Without that, any answer given cannot be understood. Writing an entire tutorial to explain an answer is beyond the scope of the site - tutorials exist elsewhere.

Comment: To continue, the users who posted those comments were also not able to see from my perspective that what they were asking me to do was something I could not do and just threw a TLDR in other words at me. Despite the fact the question was answered...

Comment: The "children misbehaving" analogy was just that, an analogy, no need to read into it and think I'm accusing everyone of being children. My accusation is that people are unkind and unhelpful due to the fact they get overwhelmed by the sheer quantity of posts, despite having no duty or obligation to answer everything.

Comment: I've just created a new account and [this is the first notification you get](https://i.imgur.com/FtkXu4s.png), [this is in the sidebar when you enter](https://i.imgur.com/FsMnOar.png). There are many other opportunities to see the FAQ resources about SO, too - when adding a question, for example, you should have some links.

Comment: @VLAZ as I said, I have no recollection of ever having a notification like that or seeing that in the sidebar. So it's good to see that the site is making efforts to dissuade hobbyists or rookies from making help-posts.

Comment: OK, I've just looked at that link. From my perspective, everyone in those comments was being extremely polite. They were trying to help *guide you* to learning on your own, rather than spoon-feeding you an answer. There's great belief here in the adage "Give a man a fish and he'll eat for a day. Teach a man to fish and he'll never go hungry." Those comments were all well meant and not trying to belittle or annoy you. If you had been able to follow that advice, you'd have acquired tools that would help you solve many future problems.

Comment: Initially, helpful, however the same comment doesn't have to be made repeatedly. I made it clear I wasn't comfortable with debugging my code and that the reprex process didn't work for me. They essentially questioned me for that after I told them I couldn't and the question had been answered.

Comment: Because these are professionals, who have at some point gone through exactly what you're experiencing, they're trying to teach you what they had to learn, often very painfully. That may be where there's a "disconnect" in perceptions. Someone asking a question is often so focussed on "I need that answer *now*" that they're unable to grasp the importance of an apparent insistence on a different way.

Comment: @CindyMeister aren't those just excuses for their attitude though? They weren't making any attempt to try and teach me and instead basically just saying "no, do it this way". I wasn't concerned about an answer **now**, I asked a question and was willing to wait, I understood it was a lot of code, but those were from a much larger and complex program that I couldn't just rewrite for a TLDR and I had already reduced to what I, from my knowledge, believed was relevant to the problem. I got two answers with the exact line causing the issue from people who didn't make any comments. That's help.

Comment: Coming at this from yet another angle: When giving an answer in a very complex programming language (and let's face it, C++ isn't simple) professionals are so aware of "this could cause that, so be careful to first understand *exactly* what's needed" that they want full context. They also want to be able to *test* a problem. And it takes a lot of time and effort to read lines and lines of code... that may have nothing to do with a problem. You're asking for their time, they tell you to please prepare the content so that they can deal with it efficiently.

Comment: "I got two answers with the exact line causing the issue from people who didn't make any comments. That's help" Yes... it's giving you the fish so that you can satisfy your hunger immediately. And the marked answer also gave you explanation and links, which is very important. Ask yourself, though, if you had been able to do what those in comments were encouraging you to do and at least been able to find where the problem was occurring... Would you have profited from that?

Comment: @CindyMeister regarding time, if they didn't have enough time to read the code, then they didn't have to, I'm not asking or forcing them in particular to do it, and I even mention that I understand the applications of reprex', but I'm just unable to provide one. They spent more time trying to challenge me in the comments while two users identified the issue with what would have been a quick scan over the code, another user made and deleted an answer because **I didn't include enough code** and they suggested something i already had.

Comment: OK, I think we've thoroughly presented the points of view :-) I'm considering how to compose an answer... FWIW if you want to bring about change, a more effective way to do so is to present concrete suggestions (using "Ask a Question") tagging as "feature request". An objective description of the problem and how the suggestion addresses it should be included. I also recommend as background reading at the very least the Stack Overflow company's blog articles about how the company (who has the final say in anything) perceives the site and where they want to go.

Comment: Ah, on reflection, one other observation: Based on the extent and tone of those comments urging you to reprex and debug... I think those people were seeing promise in your future, based on the code they did see and were therefore willing to invest so much time and effort trying to lead you to using the approaches they were suggesting - to make you a better programmer.

Comment: @CindyMeister I could understand that observation if under optimism, but I don't believe that was at all their true viewpoint because it came across as "do it this way" even after I said outright that i couldn't. When people don't take the time to try and understand something you've said, it's more disparaging than outright insults. I was new to the language and desired some sort of flexibility with how my problem was addressed. Reprex as a solution feels like an approach for one size fits all.

Comment: Doing things you can't do is what learning is at the most basic level. It's how those people trying to help you learned what they know. Removing code to isolate an issue is a trial and error thing, that's the point.

Comment: @ivarni "Trial and Error" isn't help though? It's something I had already done prior to posting my question because it's assumed common sense, I did also isolate the code as much as possible but because I genuinely couldn't isolate the code further without losing context that's important to the code, I didn't make it any smaller, and they, along with you, didn't appear to understand that despite the amount I said it.

Comment: I'm familiar with those users and can tell you from my experiences with them and reading their contributions that it was more likely their viewpoint than otherwise. :-) One thing we constantly have to tell ourselves, when dealing with people unfamiliar with site culture is: assume good intent.

Comment: It's very difficult to assume good intent when you see none, what I saw was simply "TLDR" because i had already spent considerable time reducing my code for the post, so this only irritated me further when I was already in a state over not being able to locate the problem. I think that's a thing the community sometimes forgets when a question is asked, it's usually asked because the user can't find a solution, and when they can't, they're not going to be in the best of moods. I don't know them at all, their only interaction being those comments, and there is no indication of kindness.

Comment: "*because the user can't find a solution, and when they can't, they're not going to be in the best of moods*" True, true... "*I don't know them at all, their only interaction being those comments, and there is no indication of kindness*" Ah, well, I have seen them "not in the best of moods", so I have a pont of comparison :-)

Comment: 'they can't be bothered to put in the time'. Might be a bit of a rhetorical question... How much time did *you* spend in your problem before coming here? Do recognize, please, that a lot of the new users that people complain about spend 3 minutes on their problem, then dump 2-3 hours of debugging to the community. It's not everyone. But it definitely happens.

Comment: @Patrice almost a full hour, and then I topped it off into a full hour by reducing the code. This is why I said with certainty that I couldn't simplify it any more without knowing what the problem actually was.

Comment: @Samsy 1 hour? Before I personally post.... I give it a week. Of writing, rewriting, research, work. I may be on the other extreme..... But I'd still say 2 hours is a bit little before turning to Stack. That's where the main issue lies: the site is suffering from it's success.... :/

Comment: @Patrice for the overall size of the program, an hour is more than enough, it caps at something like 400 lines total. No need to humble brag week-long efforts, especially when it's not literal at all (You didn't spend 168 hours for a single question). Your comment also does nothing to address my point. I spent an hour before getting the code smaller, they spent over an hour playing ping pong in the comments, and 2 users found answers in less time than that.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn it's not a humble brag, it's how I work with stack. And no of course it wasn't 168 hours of work. Most of the time, after 4-5 hours dissecting my stuff, I find my own answer. Notice how in my first comment I also say "do recognize, please, that a lot of the new users .... dump 2-3 hours of debugging". I didn't say you. I asked you, and then pushed it to the greater community. If you want to enact change, maybe assume good intentions of people instead of trying to attack them? I'm coming to help and highlight *my* experience, and get called bragging. That's.... nice of you.

Comment: @Patrice it came across as a brag because you tried to make an hour of work seem petty compared to the time you spend on what I assume are drastically different things. You aren't helping by saying that, it genuinely adds nothing by saying "You do that? Well I do this!" when time spent on debugging is not the topic at hand and was even unrelated to the comment I posted about the fact that they took more time arguing than they were prepared to help.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn I sympathize with your views. I don't think it is even limited to new users. My last two questions on here, both submitted after a long time trying to work them out, were down-voted and flagged as "off-topic". I have lots of experience writing a question, lots of rep across the whole SE network, and yet my questions are still not good enough for some high-rep users.

Comment: The expectations seem to be very much misaligned here.  There's some awareness of that misalignment going on, from reading the comments, but not really an attempt to conform to those expectations.  That's progress, but still not quite there.  At the end of the day, there *is* a barrier to entry here; askers have to be able to understand the problem space they're asking about, to be able to understand the answers.  The comments were an attempt to point that out, and the downvotes show that the question won't be useful to future readers.  That's what they're supposed to do.

Comment: One of those barriers is that you need to be able to debug.  It's...one of the foundational skills that *every* programmer needs, and we can't teach.  That ability is *critical* to solving programming problems, and without that, we can't help.  Not won't, but *can't*.  Everything you learn about programming is built on that base.

Comment: @fbueckert "Not won't, but *can't*" you say that when I got an answer with no debug information and just listed a short section of code?
Again, if you'd like to comment, read all the comments so far for some context, otherwise you're just repeating what other people have said or points that have been addressed.

Comment: @Samsy "I tried to make an hour petty".... wow, where's the "assuming good faith here"? I pointed out how *I* use Stack, and why my experience is different. Maybe the fact I push myself to do **more** research is why I a) don't ask a lot b) when I ask, I get good reception. I'm just highlighting how others do it to help you see if you can maybe adapt to that. All in the intent of getting you a better Stack experience. but sure, see it as bragging and me being demeaning. I don't think that's a productive stance for either side to take now :/. But whatever I guess. Best of luck for the future

Comment: @Patrice if you truly believe that: "1 hour? Before I personally post.... I give it a week." comes across as anything but a put down or bragging, then I'm worried about your social interactions. That's closed face wording, and at no point do you consider that the size of a project effects the time it takes to work on reducing the code. Bigger program = More time, it's really that simple in most cases, you're displaying the lack of sympathy I'm on about.

Comment: @Samsy lol. You made up your mind before we even started talking. You insult me repeatedly without even seeing it and call out *my* interactions. In any case, no matter the size of my issue, I do spend as long as I can to isolate it/fix it myself. Again, it was not a put down, it was to highlight the difference in how we approach the site, and explain how that might be the root cause of the difference in reception. But again... you made up your mind before you entered the room. Nothing productive can happen with that mindset :/. Have a good day

Comment: @Patrice Again, "1 hour?", shocked expression, suggests there is something about what you've heard that isn't normal, followed by "Before I personally post.... I give it a week.", a suggestion following a shocked expression, as if a week is what I should be spending, suggests normality, or in contrast, superiority. This is some very basic stuff based on the language you used, it would be a surprise if I thought anything that was not negative about what you wrote. Spend a week on the language you use and then maybe you could understand what I'm on about, you're twice as judgemental in here.

Comment: I did read all the comments.  On your question here and your answer.  And you got lucky.  That's not a common case, nor should it be.  The vast majority will not, because we just *can't* help.  The best we can do is guess.  I'm trying to point out that you don't have a skill that is *required*.  Not just here, but for programming in general.  Without that skill...I don't know what to tell you.  Any site assumes a base level of skill; ours is that you have the foundations of programming.

Comment: Reading [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364282/can-we-support-users-who-do-not-understand-how-to-debug-their-code) should help flesh out what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @fbueckert If you actually read the post, then you'd know that the issue is that it's not made clear enough that this is purely for those "professional and experienced" questions, the site is commonly referenced as a sort of help desk for programming, which it is not, so a large problem is the sourness towards any common new programmer posts. I know how to debug a program, but I cannot debug it because i don't have the resources, as I mentioned in the post people are improperly referencing.

Comment: If you don't have the resources, you don't know how to debug.  That's all there is to it.  Beyond that, it seems we're talking past each other.  You want SO to be something it's not.  All I can do is repeat myself.  It's up to you to accept it, or not.  Good bye.

Comment: @fbueckert you're going in circles and ignoring points I've made, I'm not saying StackOverflow should be something it isn't, I'm saying it should be clear about what it is, but also have the common decency to not be sour when someone makes a mistake, because believe it or not, you didn't know how to debug once.

Comment: regarding recent edit, see [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/839601) "people who come to complain/ask about posts on Stack Overflow on Meta are essentially inviting scrutiny and review of these posts..."

Comment: The rationale given to the meta effect is "you're casting a spotlight on some of your content, putting it in front of the most quality minded members this site has". I.... don't agree with it, honestly, and I do believe a lot of it comes from "I don't like your suggestion, so lemme downvote you". It's impossible to prove, but it's a shame when it happens. That's why some of the meta regulars make it a point to not vote after coming from meta on a post..... Really sucks for you though :/. Whether I agree with you or your views or not, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @gnat and from what I've seen, nobody gets punished for it, despite it being a vindictive act.

Answer (score 10):

> ...the rules, and the general meta of the forum push a narrative that Stack Overflow is an archive of questions and answers, which itself is a ridiculous goal to pursue as you've got to ask stupid questions from time to time to get a build up of good answers

Stack Overflow is indeed an archive of useful questions and answers. Every day thousands of visitors come here and find solutions to their problems even without asking a question on their own. The reason is that simply not every problem is unique. Stack Overflow is (still) a really good resource and library of relevant programming questions with useful answers.

When we answer a question we do not answer it only for a single person, but for every person that comes there afterwards too.

Is it a ridiculous goal to pursue? No, because many of the visitors looking for solutions wouldn't get help otherwise.

Is it a ridiculous goal to pursue because sometimes there are stupid questions asked? Absolutely not. We have tools in place remove stupid questions from the library part of the website. This is not a big problem if it happens only from time to time (it happens a bit more often though).

> ... nobody will come here after asking a single question ...

So far there are no real indications of that. Maybe in the future, but for now this fear might be somewhat exaggerated. Also it's fine to come here only for a single question or even without any question at all.

> ... has no chill

That is indeed a misconception often heard. Some may have no chill, but I think that many more have and still downvote, because voting (up and down) is the quality control here. Downvotes are not personal, just an indication of how useful the contribution was (and on meta not even that instead just agreement or disagreement).

> ... drop the pursuit of the idea of turning Stack Overflow into a resource ...

I guess most answerers wouldn't want that. They are here because Stack Overflow is a resource. If it wasn't, they wouldn't be here.

> ... make it clearer that this is not a place for new programmers to ask for help

Thanks for writing this. I fully agree, it really should be made as clear as possible. You need a minimal understanding of how to prepare a good question or how to search for possible duplicates. This platform here is good for improving skills (which doesn't make you an elite already, just because you have some skills), but it's not really efficient for learning from scratch. It cannot be said often enough currently.

However, we would need the help of the platform owner to make it more clear. I'm not sure that we will get it. The company behind Stack Overflow seems to want both (and may end up making both really bad).

I think you got the alternatives right, but the company kind of disagrees with you.

> ... redirect new programmers or folks with basic problems to better resources

I don't know if there are better resources out there. There may not. I would also be interested in getting to know them and if there are, I would gladly redirect new programmers there.

However, simply saying, don't go here for learning how to program should be enough in principle.

One should not forget that everything given here is voluntary work. This is all an unpaid service and there is no guarantee for getting answers. There may be paid services that provide much better tuition.

***Edit:*** In response to the edit of the question.

> The community would be improved drastically if people had an ounce of sympathy popped into them intravenously before they posted a comment or an answer ...

First, this is not formulated in a a nice way, reducing it's chances for making a compelling argument close to zero. That's unfortunate.

But even if it were formulated as something like "People should be nice to each other..." I would expect a bit more context like giving examples of what there is and what there should be and most important how it should all be implemented in for example a code of conduct or something else.

The big question is not if we should be nice to each other, but how we can achieve that.

Comment: While you make good points here, they're all ones that have been brought up in the **far too lengthy** comment chain on the main post. The quotations you took are a bit out of context, especially the "drop the pursuit one". My main point, if my badly written question had one, was that it needs to be clear that this is not a place for new programmers to ask for help, and there are better places for that (Reddit, Sololearn, Discord) and there are better resources for learning (Tutorial sites, Language sites, Youtube). Volunteering to me is not an excuse for an attitude though.

Comment: "*... nobody will come here after asking a single question ...*" about that - actually...that is fine. There *are* contributors who asked a single question and have no activity on the site later. But if the question was good, it could serve to guide many others. There are these questions. But also, people do come to SO without ever asking a question. Many are taken here from searching a problem they had on the internet and getting links to SO posts. These people may even keep coming back solely through searches without ever making an account. And that's fine too - that's the point of SO.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn "it needs to be clear that this is not a place for new programmers to ask for help" I fully agree with that. We need the help of the company for it. "Volunteering to me is not an excuse for an attitude though." I don't really see the attitude, maybe I'm too blind for it. Could you maybe make it more clear in your question where you see an attitude?

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn You're welcome to mark comments under the main post as "no longer needed" and delete your own, where you feel appropriate. And you can edit your question. Given that Trilarion has written an answer, a tldr to bring out what has crystallize as the main point of concern would be very helpful.

Comment: @Trilarion Attitude and the perception of it through text is wholly subjective and I don't think I can find a perfect example for you. Jonrsharpe's comment on my question could be an example to some, taking a confrontational stance and linking a post only for people to divert over there to downvote it some more, causing damage to my account for reasons possibly more so related to this post rather than the linked question.

Comment: @CindyMeister I'm not getting anything like that showing up, and after being sent downvotes because of **this post**, I can't even vote on comments there anymore. I will work on writing up a TLDR for this question however.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn jonrsharpe's may be a bit short, but basically he just advises you to try out debugging rather sooner than later, because it's an important skill and will help you a lot. And because Stack Overflow is a resource it could help you with this. I think there must be questions and answer dealing with "how to debug".

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn "*I'm not getting anything like that showing up*" You mean flagging comments? Do you see an up-arrow next to comments? And below that a square "thingy" with a vertical line attached? That's for flagging. Click that and you'll get a dialog box.

Comment: @Trilarion He repeated the same thing i was already being told on another post, at the time that post was not relevant to the discussion, and he linked it, soon after, a few new downvotes appear, which of course damage rep, and therefore restricts what i can actually do on the site. It was an irrelevant comment and when I pointed this out, he responded with snark.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have the flagging option, but no up arrow, due to the whole *bye bye rep* thing, and there is no "square thingy with a vertical line attached". The flag options I have are: "It contains harassment", "It's unfriendly or unkind", and "Something else", I don't have anything about deleting them or marking as no longer needed beyond the "Something else" option, which I used here for irrelevant comments to no avail.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn I see four options, the three you list, plus (in third position) "No longer needed". Note that, with exceptions (such as "Thank you") the comments are not deleted immediately. A moderator reviews and then deletes (or not). Since things on the site are in something of a turmoil and moderators a bit scarce, that can take some time :-) (BTW is the uparrow back on the main site?)

Comment: The "no longer needed" option is gated by rep? I didn't know that. Not convinced that was a good design decision.

Comment: I believe the "no longer needed" option is indeed gated by rep, I'd also highly recommend that closing conditions are reviewed to prevent future commenting when an answer is approved, I believe an option for users to close their own answer exists, but is also guarded by rep.

**TLDR:** Lots of useful things guarded by rep, disadvantageous to new users.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn A lot of those limitations are put in place to help battle spam accounts. It's unfortunate when it affects legitimate users but I think the benefits mainly outweigh the drawbacks. We need to still be able to close questions if they have accepted answers as a signal about what the community considers on topic or not. Suggesting good edits to posts that need it are a good way of getting above the lower rep thresholds.

Comment: Regarding the edit, "First, this is not formulated in a a nice way" should be StackOverflow's motto, people aren't exactly always kind and courteous here when they get a point across and it's not that people need to be nice to each other, it's that they have to try to understand where the person they're talking to is coming from. How do people be nice to each other? By understanding each other, you answered your own question without knowing it. When you understand someone, you are also able to create a much better answer to their question, the problem though, is that sympathy is time consuming

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn Complete understanding is sometimes difficult to achieve. Basic courtesies and assuming good faith may be important factors.

Comment: @Trilarion you can't have good faith with what is an exclusionary community, one that outwardly says "only experienced and professional programmers", it introduces itself with instant gatekeeping. Which is why I emphasise showing sympathy for newer programmers who have been misdirected that this is the place to go for help. Don't try and pick apart my individual points and look at the post as a whole in an exercise of sympathy. This is how the community makes new programmers and people simply looking for help or advise feel, and you can't tell me that's wrong without blatant gaslighting.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn I have sympathy with people looking for help, but I also have limited time and need to prioritize. I definitely cannot do teaching on a one to one basis. I don't think this community really can make new programmers but it can make existing programmers better and I help with that. And did I already mention that we would need the help of the company with conveying that message?

Comment: @Trilarion as I said before and will likely have to say a million times more, **this is not your job**, it's not up to you to teach people and I've made it clear that you actively shouldn't because this site isn't for that, but it isn't hard to link a subreddit or a post on another site that might be better for them, I've already mentioned sites where people are willing to give that one on one help. You don't need help to tell people "Hey, this question would be more appropriate on x, this site is for professional or experienced programmers.".

Comment: Continuing, the community can, via the Meta pages, come up with very basic and brief boilerplate responses for those duplicate or newbie posts that are kinder than just closing a post.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn "You don't need help to tell people "Hey, this question would be more appropriate on x, this site is for professional or experienced programmers.". " That is a suggestion worth discussing. To not get it lost in a heap of comments, maybe it should be its own question on meta (or part of this question). I will then surely comment on it.

Comment: but... I don't **know** reddit, their quality standards on r/programming, or the other sites you mention. Do you really think I should fling a new user around without knowing if the site will help them or not? All I *do* know is "this isn't appropriate for Stack". Is the onus on *me* to find the place for that new coder? I.... fail to see why:/

Comment: @Patrice if you don't personally know reddit, and you know something doesn't belong on SO, but you don't have a recommendation, say nothing, let someone who is more knowledgeable put forward a recommendation and close the question. Again and again I will say, this is not your job, not your responsibility, I'm not telling **you** to do something, just somebody to try.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn If we cannot/want not answer a question then closing it immediately is only consequential. A generic "look elsewhere" might be an option but I would prefer to discuss about it in a separate question, not here in comments. Not many people will read it here.

Comment: @Trilarion due to the downvote bombing caused by this post on other unrelated posts, I won't be making any more meta posts, it's up to some high-rep the community will actually listen to to pursue this any further as my account will likely end up banned because I disagree with the majority.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn I think you should be able to continue asking on meta but if not I can help you and put this feature-request forward. However, I'm away next week, so the week after it will be. You could help by compiling a list of resources where people should go instead. You mentioned Discord. Where exactly on Discord? I will check when I'm back.